# Formatting Unix timestamp with ctime in c

Tags: c, unix, unix-timestamp, ctime

I'm trying to format a 10-digit Unix time stamp (currently a  string) using ctime.

However, ctime() expects a parameter of type time_t, not a string.

What must I do before I can use ctime?
In other words, can I easily convert the string into a time_t?

Comment: Use `strtoull` (check for overflows).

Comment: @eq-: The time is a signed quantity, not unsigned.  Negative times are before 1970-01-01 00:00:00Z (and yes, that leaves an ambiguity between errors and one second before The Epoch).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, I was very aware of that. However, speaking of "10 digit" timestamp does (or at least can be interpreted to do) restrict the range to non-negative timestamps.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're saying you have something like 1346426869 as a string and want it to be a time_t?

```
time_t raw_time = atoi("1346426869");
printf("current time is %s",ctime(&raw_time));

> current time is Fri Aug 31 11:27:49 2012
```

Answer (score 0):

The time_t type is just an integer. It is the number of seconds since the Epoch. You'll need to parse the string first.

Start here:

http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/General-Time-String-Parsing.html#General-Time-String-Parsing

and work your way forward from there.