# Transforming Unix Timestamp in milliseconds to a normal date

Tags: c++, datetime, timestamp

For example I have the number(in milliseconds) 1439467747492 and I need to transform it in a data format.The number will return:
Thu, 13 Aug 2015 12:09:07 GMT.

Is a function to do that or I need a specific code to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you need [this](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ctime.3.html). Answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12286369/formatting-unix-timestamp-with-ctime-in-c)

Comment: What is the reference point for these millisecond timestamps? Since epoch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    time_t a = 1439467747492 / 1000; // or 1439467747
    std::cout << "The time is " << ctime(&a);
}
```